# android studio - Image Asset showing andriod icon instead of the icon I put

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am making an app icon [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher).

After that, I put the icon in 
[image]

Then I right click > New > Image Asset, it shows default android icon instead of my icon.[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: brother simply open your android folder  in android studio and go to add image asset and upload an icon and it will appear rather than using website to generate icons.its simple way to change app icon

Comment: can you able to see it in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add icon your self

There are following steps to create adaptive icon:

1. Upgrade Android Studio to newest version
2. Right click to res folder > New > Image Asset
3. You can find (Foreground Layer / Background Layer / Options) tabs
4. Select your foreground icon under Foreground Layer's tab
5. Select your background icon under Background Layer's tab
6. Click next -> finish to create adaptive icon

There are following steps to create lagacy icon:

1. Upgrade Android Studio to newest version
2. Right click to res folder > New > Image Asset
3. In icon type, select Launcher Icons(Legacy Only)
4. Asset type, choose image
5. select your path
6. Click next -> finish to create legacy launcher icon